How to build ActorSystem in Flink 1.13.5?
This is how I build ActorSystem in Flink 1.8.5.
public static ActorSystem createNewActorSystem() throws Exception {
    String ip = HostPortUtil.getLocalIp();
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setString(MetricOptions.QUERY_SERVICE_PORT, portRange);
    // remote actorsystem
    ActorSystem actorSystem = MetricUtils.startMetricsActorSystem(configuration, ip, logger);
    return actorSystem;
}

And I want to build ActorSystem in Flink 1.13.5?
How should I modify the code?
I check the document and try to use RobustActorSystem class to build ActorSystem. However, it is totally different.
So I have no idea how to fix this.
